# WPF define DataContext in control inside `ItemsControl`

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have a `MainWindow` with its `xaml` and `MainViewModel` and a `FahrtControl` with its `xaml` and `FahrtControlViewModel`. Inside the `MainViewModel`, I have an `ObservableCollection` of `FahrtControlViewModel`. Inside `MainWindow.xaml` I have a `DataTemplate`, connecting the `FahrtControlViewModel` and `FahrtControl`:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fahrtControl:FahrtControlViewModel}">
    <fahrtControl:FahrtControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

as well as an `ItemsControl` inside a `StackPanel`:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FahrtControlViewModelCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Inside the `FahrtControlViewModel`, I have a constructor which receives some values from the initialization of the `MainViewModel` - that means, it takes some arguments (this'll be relevant later, stick with me).

Inside `FahrtControl.xaml.cs`'s constructor, I call `InitializeComponent`:

```
public FahrtControl ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
}
```

and inside `FahrtControl.xaml` I'd *like* to set the `DataContext` (it works without it, but then Rider doesn't get the suggestions right anymore):

```xml
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <fahrtControl:FahrtControlViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

However, this leads to

1. A Rider warning in `FahrtControl.xaml`: *No default constructor found*
2. An exception upon initialization of the control:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.DefaultBinder.BindToMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, Object[]& args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String[] names, Object& state)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.BindToMethod(BindingFlags bindingFlags, MethodBase[] candidates, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.DynamicMethodRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(Type type, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.DynamicMethodRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at WpfFrontend...FahrtControl.InitializeComponent() in D:\...\FahrtControl\FahrtControl.xaml:line 1
   at WpfFrontend...FahrtControl..ctor() in D:\...\FahrtControl\FahrtControl.xaml.cs:line 12
```

So there are two possible solutions that come to mind:

1. Remove the call to `InitializeComponent` in `FahrtControl.xaml.cs`
2. Adding an empty default constructor

However, both solutions lead to the controls not being displayed / not containing the relevant data (I can't actually tell the difference). I assume that the first one leads to them not being displayed (because they aren't initialized) and the second one to them being empty (because the default constructor is called and the filled `FahrtControlViewModel` is overwritten with a fresh and empty one.

I've had this problem for years and always ignored it (as only the Rider suggestions / syntax highlighting are affected), but this really annoys me and I want to solve the problem properly.

Comment: Setting the UserControl's DataContext in its XAML overrides the inherited DataContext value from the ContentPresenter in the ItemsControl. The UserControl will hence not show the item from the ItemsSource collection, i.e. not work as expected. So remove the DataContext assignment.

Comment: Also note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that this tries to instantiate a **new** instance of FahrtControlViewModel (which is not possible, as it has no parameterless constructor). If it would be possible, it would simply overwrite the data context at runtime.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <fahrtControl:FahrtControlViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Instead, you may want to use the following:

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance fahrtControl:FahrtControlViewModel}"
```

Please be aware that this is the way how it is done in Visual Studio, but I assume, that it works also in Rider.

Comment: I would also include xmlns:mc and xmlns:d in your example. From what OP has descibed, this has never been used by OP so probably as an attempt in "optimising" the xaml those have been removed.

Comment: @XAMlMAX it actually works without the other options - all I need is to set the `DataContext` as in the last line of the example. What are the other options for?

Comment: `mc:Ignorable="d"` means that an element with the `d:` namespace will be ignored (as if it were commented out) by the Xaml parser. `mc` is the markup-compatibility namespace.